# Apache Resource Utilization Coupled with MySQL

Tags: mysql, apache, resources

When checking Production, an Apache thread was seen to be using up a lot of resources.

Is it possible this could be a bit misleading "in that", the actual culprit is caused by MySQL, if the site happened to be using MySQL.

Comment: How are you checking the resource consumption? It might be something that's ran by Apache (PHP) that uses MySQL and then problem occurs somewhere when the data from MySQL is being received or utilized in some way. MySQL usually runs in its own process, you'd see MySQL using resources clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is definitely possible.  However, if you see the httpd thread using a lot of resources, it's Apache.  It could be some sort of interaction between httpd and mysqld.  Try examining the logs of Apache and Mysql.

Some more info will help:
Are they both running on the same server? Can you be more specific about the problem and what causes it?